# Mininet ping/iperf3 got unstable measurement results

Tags: mininet

**Expected/Desired Behavior:**
Mininet should return stable ping RTT results, after setting the network conditions with Linux tc netem.

**Actual Behavior:**
[image]

**Detailed Steps to Reproduce the Behavior:**

```bash
sudo mn # start the default topo h1---s1---h2
s1 tc qdisc add dev s1-eth2 root handle 1: netem delay 20ms loss 0.01% # this will emulate 20ms RTT
h1 ping h2
```

**Additional Information:**
I am running Mininet 2.3.0 on Virtual Box in my win10 laptop.
The VM OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and I upgraded the Linux kernel to 4.15.
Only a host-only adapter is set in VM:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have also seen this in the past and wondered. While I do not have a clear answer, here are a few possible explanations.

From your screenshot, I would assume your set RTT was 20 ms and I will work with it going forward.

The very first sample that you get has inflated RTT, since this is the first packet going through the controller and it is setting up the rules which has an increased latency.

After that, the difference in the probes that you get *could* be explained by:

1. OS imprecision. Since all components are emulated and it happens in real time, there might not be enough processing power to serve packets all the time
2. (More likely) Misconfigured link properties. Mininet links expose an option called [`max_queue_size`](http://mininet.org/api/classmininet_1_1link_1_1TCIntf.html). This is, how many packets can be buffered on this link before they get dropped. Naturally, packets sitting in the buffers will have an added propagation or buffering delay on top of their minimum path RTT measurement. I suspect this might be what you are observing since the "bad" samples seem to be clustered, hinting queuing possibly queued packets. [This article](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2071893#:%7E:text=Today%27s%20networks%20are%20suffering%20from,without%20sufficient%20thought%20or%20testing.) explaining how queuing delay affects network links.

Comment: I got a solution to solve my problem, that is, set your VM configuration to only one CPU core. After that, the monitored RTT becomes very stable only except for  the very first ICMP packet. Therefore, more likely it was due to VM OS imprecision.

Comment: Instead of using VM to run mininet, it is suggested to run it on physical machines to avoid potential problems.

Comment: Did you follow a specific guide? I wonder if it is possible to run mininet inside a VM, only assign one core to that process, while allowing the VM to be created with more power for the other processes to use.

Comment: No specific guide. just change your VM software (VMWare, VirtualBox, etc. ) settings to assign only one CPU to the VM where mininet runs @Misho Janev

Comment: @ICYPOLE I need the VM to have more juice for other processes running on it :(. I was wondering if there was a way to assign only 1 core to the mininet process alone and let the rest use whatever is available.